# how to move my login form in mobile media query

Tags: css

I am trying to move my login form to the right of screen and have tried to use positioning or margin but can't get it to move in my mobile media query. I thought that by using either margin or positioning should make it move but it doesn't and I am not sure what else to try. I have also changed my position to relative instead of using absolute but it still doesn't move it

```
header div.nav-login{

   position: absolute;
   top: 9em !important;
  margin-left: -5em !important;

}


header div.nav-login ::placeholder {
   color: #6A5ACD;
   opacity: 1;
   font-size: .7em;
}

header div.nav-login input[type='password'] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8em;
}

header div.nav-login input[type='password']::placeholder {
  position: relative;
  left: 1em;
  font-size: .7em;

}

 header div.nav-login form{
    padding-top: 40px;

}

header div.nav-login form input{
   float:left;
   width: 5.8em;
   height: 2.5em;
   padding-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 10px !important;
   border:none;
   background-color: #ccc;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #111;
   line-height: 20px;

}

header div.nav-login form button{
   float:left;
   width: 60px;
   height: 30px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   border:none;
   background-color: #FFF8DC;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #111;
   cursor:pointer;
   position: absolute;
   left: 15.5em;
   top: 3.2em;
}

header div.nav-login form button:hover{
   background-color: #ccc;

}

header div.nav-login a{
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border:none;
    float:left;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #111;
    line-height: 63px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

header div.nav-login [type=password]::placeholder  {

  left: 1em;
}

html code:
```

```
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
                }  else {

            if (isset($_SESSION['u_uid']) )  {




               echo '<form action="includes/logout.php" method="POST" class="logout">
               <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
            </form><div class="trophy"><a href="reward_points.php"><i class=" fas fa-trophy fa-4x" title="Click here to view your rewards!"></i></a></div>';

             }  else {

               echo '<form action="includes/login.php" method="POST">
                  <input  type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/e-mail">
                   <input  type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Login</button></form>';




          }
```

Comment: Add your html code please.

Comment: my html code is within my php code

Comment: I have modified my code a bit... just got rid of some sensitive data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class login-form to your form

```
<form action="includes/login.php" method="POST" class="login-form">
       <input  type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/e-mail">
       <input  type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
       <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

and add this to your css

```
.login-form {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: I have a header.nav-login form input{}; can I add it there?

Comment: I actuall have that class already called header.nav-login form{} but I thought that the positioning should go in the main form called header.nav-login {}? I mean, I thought that is my main nav-login and I didn't think about adding it in the nav-login form{}

Comment: I was watching the video tutorial again and I think that is my container

Comment: Did you fix it or still have problem? If not then share me whole page code, i can fix it for you.

Comment: but I need help with something else and I had been asking the questions a few times

Comment: I have got ipn working with my subscriptionform but not for a donation button

Comment: I can't find any solution here because someone mentioned that a donation button does not support ipn

Answer (score 0):

use media queries in your CSS.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:200px)
{
     /* Your CSS Code For Mobile Style */
}
```

Comment: I have include a media query of max-width: 568px

Comment: everything else is moving so far except my login

Comment: You can add class to the login form tag and assign it css code for moving like margin, padding or float any one of them in css media queries.